# Prevent Voice Over from reading readonly attribute in text input

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, voiceover

Is there a way to prevent VoiceOver/TalkBack to read readOnly attribute from a text input using javascript/CSS?

`<input type="text" readonly>`

I don't want this **readonly** attribute to be read on VO.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan Does it look fine to you now?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want "read only" to be announced, then remove the `readonly` attribute.

The screen reader is doing **exactly** what it is supposed to be doing.  If a visually impaired user is using your website, and they're using VoiceOver to access it, and the put their focus on the field, if they **don't** hear "read only", how will they know that they can't type in that field?